# what does null means for Serversocket in java

Tags: sockets

I am a beginner in java socket programming, and i have this line 
what does null means in this case?

```
         serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port);
                if (serverSocket != null){
.
.
.
.}
```

is it mean that socket existed or is connected??

Answer (score 1):

The code snippet you list makes no sense. A constructor in Java either returns a non-null result or throws an exception. In other words:  The `if` statement checking for non-null on the `serverSocket` variable is not needed. If you use a reasonable IDE like NetBeans (I believe the same is true for Eclipse and Intellij IDEA as well), it will flag this an unnecessary check for null.